# Why applying the same data twice breaks a chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to chart some data, then refine them in the background, and update the chart with new data.

In order to do so, I tested what would happen when reapplying the same data. The graph is displayed correctly **but the labels are gone**.

Below is the code that reproduces the issue

- when ran as it, the graph is OK
- whenever I re-apply `data` (changed or not), the graph breaks (three first comment blocks)
- if I apply a fresh Array of data (the same ones are previously), the graph is fine (fourth comment block)

```js
let data = [
  ['a', 'b', 1],
  ['a', 'c', 1]
]
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: data,
    type: 'sankey'
  }]
})

// the problems:

// the line below breaks the chart
// chart.series[0].setData(data)

// these ones breaks it too (same data in "data")
// data[0] = ['a', 'b', 1]
// chart.series[0].setData(data)

// these ones breaks it too (modified data in "data")
// data[0] = ['a', 'x', 1]
// chart.series[0].setData(data)

// this does not break it
//chart.series[0].setData([
//  ['a', 'b', 1],
//  ['a', 'c', 1]
//])
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

**How can I modify `data` to be able to re-apply it to the graph?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not repeatedly use the same data reference. Highcharts for performance uses a reference to the original data array and can modify it.

To workaround, you can use a function that will return a new data array each time:

```
function getData() {
    return [
        ['a', 'b', 1],
        ['a', 'c', 1]
    ]
}

let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: getData(),
        type: 'sankey'
    }]
});

chart.series[0].setData(getData());
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/th4wemdn/

Answer (score 1):

You can try remove the data from the chart, and add the new data modified, like this.

```js
let data = [
  ['a', 'b', 1],
  ['a', 'c', 1]
]
let chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: data,
    type: 'sankey'
  }]
})

// the problems:

// the line below breaks the chart
//var seriesLength = chart.series.length;
//    for(var i = seriesLength -1; i > -1; i--) {
//        
//    }
chart.series[0].remove();
chart.addSeries({keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],data: data, type:'sankey'});
//chart.series[0].setData(data)

// these ones breaks it too (same data in "data")
// data[0] = ['a', 'b', 1]
// chart.series[0].setData(data)

// these ones breaks it too (modified data in "data")
 data[0] = ['a', 'x', 1]
// chart.series[0].setData(data)
chart.series[0].remove();
chart.addSeries({keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],data: data, type:'sankey'});

// this does not break it
//chart.series[0].setData([
//  ['a', 'b', 1],
//  ['a', 'c', 1]
//])
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the "highcharts" api doesn't like the reference created when assigning JS objects. You could try `Object.assign(data)` or `Object.create(data)`

Here's more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Unfortunately neither `create` or `assign` solve the issue.